# What's the meaning of this symbol?

Tags: probability

This is a probability

[|, |]

What does this symbol mean? (|)

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Possibly a similar question to: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110194/what-do-vertical-bars-mean-in-statistical-distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110194/what-do-vertical-bars-mean-in-statistical-distributions)

Comment: Thank you so much!! <3

Comment: context? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the conditional  probability of $B,C$  given $M$. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

Comment: Thank you so much, life saver! <3